# How to help a beginner with speaking?

Tags: teaching-methods, speaking, teaching

I am going to help a student with speaking in my native language who is at beginner level.

**How would we have the conversation such that the student can take the most out of it?**

Some points I made up so far:

- Speak slowly.
- Speak clearly.
- Make short sentences, avoid complicated grammatical structures.
- Keep it one level above their current level so that you don't over-correct.

What else is important to keep in mind when teaching a beginner to speak? I have no educational background on teaching.

I have already asked a similar question [in the Stack Exchange of my language (German).](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61847/how-to-help-a-beginner-to-speak-german)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. I wonder if you could be a bit more precise about the level you have in mind? "Beginner" is very vague. Is the student at a specific CEFR level? Do you know how many hours of instruction they've had? Are you aware of specific difficulties they have?

Comment: The student is at A1 level. I know that the student is self-conscious. However, ideally I do not want to include specific difficulties in this question such that it can be applicable for a wide range of students

Answer (score 1):

You can use body language because every person in world uses it. For example, if you say "I" and try to make him/her understand what you say, you can point yourself with your index finger, so that the student can understand that you are talking about yourself. Or if you are talking about flying, you can shake your arms up and down.